# Use of max-width, max-height in combination with width, height

Tags: css

I beginning to learn css, and I am writing code based on a course am watching. The author has written the style for left bar images to look like this:

```
.left-side img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 140px;
max-height: 140px;
}
```

What's the use of width: 100% and height: 100%. Removing them seems to not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current image has original size of 32x32 pixels, you can replace the same image with other image of 512x512px,

`width: 100%` - no matter, what is the actual width of image, stretch it to 100% width of parent container

`height: 100%;` - no matter, what is the actual height of image, stretch it to 100% height of parent container

`max-width: 140px;` - if image is big, limit it to this value or if smaller, width100% will stretch it till 140px

`max-height: 140px;`- if image is big , limit it to this value or if smaller, height100% will stretch it till 140px

```css
.left-side img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<h1>image: 32X32</h1>

<div class="left-side">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/instagram-32.png" alt="32X32" title="32X32">
</div>

<hr>

<h1>image: 512X512</h1>

<div class="left-side">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-flat-rounded-rects/512/instagram-512.png" alt="512X512" title="512X512">
</div>
```